# Run Fast and Jump for Joy: Winter Bash 2020 Photo Album

Tags: discussion, winterbash

For many of us, role playing games provide an escape from the world, allowing us to be someone else in another universe, together with friends, new and old. As we near the end of 2020, let us celebrate this community we have built - a community founded upon helping others and making friends in other worlds, and in this one.

2020 has taught us that the time we have is precious, so run fast. Run fast toward those you love. Run fast toward new friends, new opportunities to love someone.

*And jump for joy when you get there.*

---

Every Hatmas, we wear and see fun and dapper combinations of hats: the hats go away at the end of the Hatmas season, but we can still preserve some memories and pictures of the fabulous hattery we've seen. To that end:

**Let's have a fun and/or slightly embarrassing yearbook.** Post the great hats and hatments you've seen. Show off the ones *you* made for yourself which you think are fantastic or fabulous or the greatest. If you spy an excellent thing in the wild, I guess you can stick that here too.

I recommend one answer per person (or a small number), and revise it to make additions. Keep it silly, keep it fun, and be kind. (Everyone's going to feel self conscious posting anything here, so I suggest we leave criticism at the door.)

---

### How do I take a screenshot?

- Use the **Lightshot** extension [for **Firefox**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lightshot/) or [for **Chrome**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lightshot-screenshot-tool/mbniclmhobmnbdlbpiphghaielnnpgdp?hl=en).
- **Windows 10:** press <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> for the built-in [Snipping Tool](https://superuser.com/a/404279/50208). In Windows 7, you'll have to search for that tool in the start menu. Otherwise take a screenshot of your browser with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>print screen</kbd>, crop it in MS Paint, and save it as a PNG (not GIF or JPEG).
- **Mac:** press <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>, then click and drag to outline the region you want to screenshot. The screenshot will be saved to your desktop.
- **On Linux:** Gnome/Ubuntu: press <kbd>shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>print screen</kbd>, then click-and-drag over the region you want to screenshot and save the screenshot somewhere. If the shortcut doesn't work, either set it up in System Settings/Keyboard/shortcuts/screenshots or use a tool like [Shutter](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/shutter).

[Here's a magic link to your public profile](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile) that's perfect for screenshots.

Answer (score 8):

I'm moving house, but starting next week I'm going to be drawing pictures for these avatars, mark my words.

Be safe!

[image: social distancing (meta)]

Comment: I hope to have the rainbow puke hat by then. Lift with your legs, not your back!

Comment: whoops, looks like this entire week got eaten by moving and then xmas preparations. that wasn't the plan! drawing: next week!

Answer (score 7):

Here's the start of my photo album page:

[image: my avatar with a messy hair hat]

Answer (score 7):

#### The many hats of Markov.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: this makes me wish I could bounty on meta

Answer (score 3):

Who needs hats:

[image: Fancy Mask (tm)]

I rather have a *Fancy Mask (tm)*

Comment: Sword Cthulhu it is!

Comment: @AncientSwordRage: Swordthulhu?

Comment: @ancient I was more or less going for  [Davy Jones PotC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davy_Jones_(Pirates_of_the_Caribbean)#/media/File:Piratedavyjones.JPG)

Comment: @PatrickArtner well it works!