# Winterbash: Gimme all your Hatting!

Tags: discussion, winterbash

To continue [Thomas' tradition](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11867/75095) (which was a continuation of [doppelgreener's tradition](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5964/62294)) of collecting the memorabilia of transient hat awards (and maybe also share the how we got secret hats? I think I got one but failed to record it, grrr... but there is a treasure map [how to find them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384707/winter-summer-bash-2022-hat-list-%EF%B8%8F-%EF%B8%8F/384708#384708)) here is a post for sharing selfies this year -- with hats! Apparently there is no special theme this year (but thanks to Splunk for sponsoring the event).

I'm only a poor hobgoblin, so I'll just say: be nice to people, and leave earth better than you found it.

What follows is the template from Thomas (which he copied from doppel), explaining how this works:

---

Every Hatmas, we wear and see fun and dapper combinations of hats: the hats go away at the end of the Hatmas season, but we can still preserve some memories and pictures of the fabulous hattery we've seen. To that end:

**Let's have a fun and/or slightly embarrassing yearbook.** Post the great hats and hatments you've seen. Show off the ones *you* made for yourself which you think are fantastic or fabulous or the greatest. If you spy an excellent thing in the wild, I guess you can stick that here too.

I recommend one answer per person (or a small number), and revise it to make additions. Keep it silly, keep it fun, and be kind. (Everyone's going to feel self conscious posting anything here, so I suggest we leave criticism at the door.)

---

### How do I take a screenshot?

- Use the **Lightshot** extension [for **Firefox**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lightshot/) or [for **Chrome**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lightshot-screenshot-tool/mbniclmhobmnbdlbpiphghaielnnpgdp?hl=en).
- **Windows 10:** press <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> for the built-in [Snipping Tool](https://superuser.com/a/404279/50208). In Windows 7, you'll have to search for that tool in the start menu. Otherwise take a screenshot of your browser with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>print screen</kbd>, crop it in MS Paint, and save it as a PNG (not GIF or JPEG).
- **Mac:** press <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>, then click and drag to outline the region you want to screenshot. The screenshot will be saved to your desktop.
- **On Linux:** Gnome/Ubuntu: press <kbd>shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>print screen</kbd>, then click-and-drag over the region you want to screenshot and save the screenshot somewhere. If the shortcut doesn't work, either set it up in System Settings/Keyboard/shortcuts/screenshots or use a tool like [Shutter](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/shutter).

[Here's a magic link to your public profile](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile) that's perfect for screenshots.

Answer (score 9):

#### Thomas watching comment discussions that don't concern him:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I normally don't care for the hats, and I'm normally quite inactive, but I popped in and decided to post some corrections in a comment on an ancient answer for an ancient question just in case someone came around looking at it.  Pretty sure that's how I got this secret hat called "Back in My Day".  IDK, could be totally unrelated.  I definitely wouldn't recommend going around commenting on ancient questions for no reason.  Was my first hat though and I like it so I figured I'd commemorate it here.

[image: you youngins don't know what it was like]

Comment: You are right, you get this for interacting with an old post. You can get it even by just upvorting a question or answer older than 5 years.

Comment: Ah, that explains the recent run of upvotes on posts of mine from 2016 and 2017 =D

Comment: @nitsua60 I assume those are more related to the everything everywhere at once hat ;)

Comment: @Akixkisu Probably two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 6):

Copied from [my answer to the corresponding MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384850/335251):

---

When one pair of sunglasses isn't enough...

[image: Shizuo... with another pair of sunglasses]

(To be fair, Shizuo does have a tendency to break things.)

Answer (score 5):

It can be a little difficult to find a good hat when your avatar is a mermaid looking sideways, but then the site slam dunked this hat into my closet and it's *so* on theme. I love it.

[image: pirate hat]

I also ate a cupcake and wore a pilot hat for a bit, and I got the sun for my solstice hat. Also the 2023 glasses look pretty good on me!

[image: cupcake]
[image: pilot hat]
[image: solstice]
[image: glasses]

Once I got my 11 hat, Akixkisu gave me the idea to wear it like a flower.

[image: 11 as a flower]

Answer (score 4):

This *literally* what Groody do here most days. Read book, tell answer. Good DM screen, too! "I Voted" hat is for upvoting or downvoting. Groody only upvote of course in holiday time, no nasty downvoting! Punish later, for Magubliet's glory.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Is rules lawyer hat for visiting boring Code of Conduct page, but Groody like better to dress up as Santa! Even better Santa beard for Hobgoblin is wild and yellow. Next one say is Albert Einstein, but Groody know, is no Stein, really is nice Santa beard. Also nice Santa beard in violet -- is gift from Dame Edna!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: So many different kinds of Santa beards!

Comment: What's the source for your profile image?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov It is the Hobgoblin card from the board game "Talisman"

Comment: It would be funnier if you turned the book upside down, since everyone knows hobgoblins can't read.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov You are entirely right about it being funnier. I just tried it on for size, unfortunately, as the book is angled, it looks much more as if the hobgoblin is behind a DM screen when you turn it on its head, not as if he is reading it. (Although that might also not be bad use of the book).

Answer (score 4):

### A failed metamorphosis, teeth engulfed the petals.

[image: A failed metamorphosis, teeth engulfed the petals.]

Comment: This one works really well with your profile picture!

Comment: I'll admit it--I've never actually looked closely at what "purple and black squiggle" actually was :bashful_shrug:

Comment: @nitsua60 please no accidential grazing ;)

Answer (score 4):

Winter Bash comes, and headwear is abound.

I pick just one, from all those found.

No more is needed, no matter what.

Because I got myself - look just at that

Good ol' dice and a cat in a hat.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Community](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) is now wearing a hat!

[image: community wearing the verified hat]

(or is that more like a costume at this point?)

Answer (score 3):

[image: ironman]

"I Am Iron Man"

Answer (score 3):

### The Ferret must wear a hat

[image: a cartoon ferret with a pirate hat from the winter bash superimposed]

### Also my [Data Hat](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/270703/3804) looks nothing like [Lt. Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_(Star_Trek))

[image: a cartoon ferret with a cave safety helmet with the brand Splunk on it]